# Prove that a family F of analytic functions in closed unit disc D, F is locally uniformly bounded in D if and only if F is uniformly bounded in D

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that a family F of analytic functions in closed unit disc D
is locally uniformly bounded in D if and only if 
F is uniformly bounded in D

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Answer (score 1):

Uniformly bounded $\implies$ locally uniformly bounded is trivial.

For the other direction, for each $z\in D$ let $U_{z}$ be an open neighborhood of $z$ that is both small enough to be contained in $D$ and such that $F$ is uniformly bounded on it, say by $M_{z}$.  Then $D$ is covered by $\{ U_{z} | z\in D \}$, hence, since $D$ is compact, there are finitely many $z$'s, say, $z_{1},...,z_{n}$, such that $D$ is covered by $\{U_{z_{1}},...,U_{z_{n}}\}$.  Let $M = max\{M_{z_{1}},...,M_{z_{n}}\}$.  Then $F$ is uniformly bounded by $M$ on $D$.

You might also want to say something about analytic continuation or you might not.